# push a $scope object to a view on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Currently i have an array as a $scope object

```
$scope.data {
  item1: "Value",
  item2: "Value Alt"
}
```

each item relates to a form input and default value, I want to be able to create a new form from the same set of data on an ng-click event and also achieve the result I tried using `jQuery.clone` but it broke the form and the form validation

Comment: You need to provide more details in question. The question is not clear.

Comment: i want to duplicate my form, on a button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `angular.copy` to clone object.

Usage

```
angular.copy(source[, destination]);
```

in your case :

```
 $scope.data  = {
   item1: "Value",
   item2: "Value Alt"
}

$scope.mydata = angular.copy($scope.data);

if will clone object $scope.data
```

for more detail [read this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy)